# The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found while Implementing IComparer Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, icomparer

I am trying to implement `IComparer` Interface in my code

```
public class GenericComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {

        throw NotImplementedException;
    }
}
```

But this throws an error

> Error 10  The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have no idea, what's going wron. Can any one point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the name of your class, I think you meant to implement the *generic* [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the *non-generic* `IComparer`.

If so, you need to make your class generic, and declare the generic type parameter `T`

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {    
        throw NotImplementedException;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your GenericComparer isn't generic - and you're implementing the [non-generic `IComparer` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx). So there *isn't* any type `T`... you haven't declared a type parameter `T` and there's no named type called `T`. You probably want:

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
```

Either that, or you need to change your `Compare` method to:

```
public int Compare(object x, object y)
```

... but then it would be a pretty oddly named class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to implement `IComparer<T>`:

```
public class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        throw NotImplementedException;
    }
}
```